# How can i display "Time Elapsed" information from program in c++?

Tags: c++, time

I have a c++ program running in vs2010 as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
long factorial(int n)
{
    int counter;
    long fact = 1;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++)
    {
        fact = fact * counter;
    }
    Sleep(100);
    return fact;
}

int main(void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    LARGE_INTEGER t0, tF, tDiff;
    double elapsedTime;
    double resolution;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t0);
    // code to be timed goes HERE
    {
        factorial(10);
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&tF);
    tDiff.QuadPart = tF.QuadPart - t0.QuadPart;
    float deltaseconds = ((float)tDiff.QuadPart)/((float) freq.QuadPart);
    elapsedTime = tDiff.QuadPart / (double) freq.QuadPart;
    printf("Code under test took %lf sec\n", elapsedTime);
    return 0;
}
```

This program displays the time taken by factorial. Now when i build it then in build window i see :

```
1>Build succeeded.
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.36
```

Now , i want to get "Time Elapsed" information to be displayed from my program also. So, suggest me how can i fetch this information and display it through my program only or by using some other interface.

Comment: you do realize that 'Time Elapsed' here refers to the time it took for the project to build. Are you sure that's what you want your program to display?

Comment: Can't you just change the text in the `printf` statement?

Comment: By actually executing the program - output appearing in the output window

Comment: @Pandrei yes i want time it took for project to build.

Comment: @anamikaemail build time is something the build-chain (or tools in general) you use would know internally. For your program to know, at runtime, about something that took place at buildtime, when it did not exist, it would have to get it from something like a file or memory location. But that is entirely dependent on the build-chain and generally not straight forward go get, most of the time not available.

Comment: Feels like your program is not born to know anything by itself. You can write another program and connect it to VS and use that program as a server and connect your new borne program to that server to get the time. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131116/vc-how-to-hook-unhook-a-particular-single-thread

Comment: @Pandrei so is there no way i can get the build time displayed from program while runtime. You mentioned to get it from something like a file , can you elaborate how?

Comment: @anamikaemail that info would be very specific to VS and not widely spread. So, the answer to your question is - No, I don't know how you can get it. But I would raise the question on one of MS's dedicated forums.